# UIview animation interrupted IOS

Tags: ios

I am moving two UIButtons with this animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^{

                             self.ViewA.frame = CGRectMake(self.ViewA.frame.origin.x, self.ViewA.frame.origin.y - 174, self.ViewA.frame.size.width, self.ViewA.frame.size.height);
                             self.ViewB.frame = CGRectMake(self.ViewB.frame.origin.x, self.ViewB.frame.origin.y - 174, self.ViewB.frame.size.width, self.ViewB.frame.size.height);
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         }];
```

but as the animation runs until the user holds his finger on a UIButton, if he releases the animation is interrupted. Is there a method, or something to determine when this happens and fix the position of the buttons?

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: in if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

Comment: What do you mean by interrupted? What happens?

Comment: if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded||[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled||[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed){ gets called when the user releases the finger and a new animation starts

Comment: Your problem still isn't clear. Are you performing a different animation when the above conditions are met? If so, then the animation should be interrupted. You should post the whole code in the gesture recognizer's action method so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

In your completion block, the `finished` parameter tells you whether your animation has completed or not. If its value is `NO`, then the animation has been terminated. This is how you know if you need to fix the positions, etc.